# Update a column on rows of which another column has multiple values

Tags: mysql, where-in

I am having trouble with something like this:

```
UPDATE `database` SET `col1` = 0 WHERE `col2` in (1,2,3,4);
```

Following is an actual failed query.

```
Error Message:
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@cc3.biz, sales@allservico.com)' at line 1
```

SQL:

```
UPDATE `CubeCart_customer` SET `optIn1st` = 0 WHERE `email` in (markscarts@cc3.biz, sales@allservico.com);
```

I have searched the web, and here, and tried several variations in my code to produce the query, but I just can't pinpoint where I'm failing.

Any light on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around your string values

```
UPDATE CubeCart_customer 
SET optIn1st = 0
WHERE email in ('markscarts@cc3.biz', 'sales@allservico.com');
```

Comment: Ah, I see. The values are entered into a textarea on html page as email addresses separated by commas, so I will have to process my $_POST['edit_group'] string to insert the quotes and try that. Thank you.

Comment: That opens the door to SQL injections. It would be best and easier to just use *Prepared Statements*. Look up a tutorial. It is easy and you don't need to worry about quotes anymore.